2016 TV series about people helping other people by taking over their minds/bodies
I saw a series premiere for TV series on TV but when I tried looking for it nothing shows up:

American TV show debuted around the late summer-fall 2016
From what I got from trailer was that a couple of people (about 4-5 people, I think the main character is white male) that help people by taking over their minds/bodies to help them solve their problems
I thought was called "Falling Water" but it's not. That's a completely different show. I remember it had some long name like "When the rain drop falls" or something. (I could be wrong, but I swear I remember they had similar titles).

I know it's a big of a stretch but I looked up 2016 and 2017 TV shows. I don't even know what company made it because it was airing on CTV Canada. It was premiering about the same time as Timeless.

Sounds somewhat like Travelers.

It pretty much has to be Travelers. You should probably add that as an answer.

I think you may be referring to Travelers, a new series that premiered on Canadian TV channel Showcase in October 2016 (within a couple weeks of Timeless) and was subsequently released on Netflix (US) in December. While this is a different network than you mentioned it does match much of your criteria. The basic premise, quoted from Wikipedia, is:

A team of special operatives, sent back in time from the future, are
  tasked with preventing the collapse of society. These operatives,
  known as travelers, inhabit the body of an individual from the 21st
  century moments before the individual's "recorded time of death".

Actor Eric McCormack, best known for his role as Will Truman in the sitcom Will & Grace, plays Traveler 3468 who assumes the identity of FBI agent Grant MacLaren.


You're the BEST!!! Thanks so much! I thought it was American because of all the American premiers showing on the tv (ie Timeless).

You weren't wrong, it's a joint Canadian-American production.

The premise has a Quantum Leap vibe. Is it worth watching?

@Taladris I tuned in to the first couple of episodes because I liked Brad Wright's work on Stargate Universe but this show wasn't for me.  I tend to be picky though.
